# R: Calculate percentage of activities with "Gloves". Ie. count as TRUE if "Gloves" exists for each ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame df with a series of surfaces that are touched during particular activities (coded 1 to 5).

```
df<-tibble(Surface=sample(c("Gloves","foo","bar","AlcoholGel","Sink"),50,replace = TRUE),ActivityID=rep(1:5,each=10))
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of activities (`ActivityID`) that have at least 1 occurrence of "Gloves".

I'm trying the following `dplyr` code but it over-counts because there might be more than 1 instance in "Gloves" in each ActivityID. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

```
require(dplyr)
    df%>%
      group_by(ActivityID)%>%
      summarise(sum(match(Surface,"Gloves"),na.rm = TRUE))
```

I'd like to see a summary table of activities that have Gloves in their list of surface (if calculating the percentage in one go is not so easy.

Comment: Your title and question body does not seem to match. Can you show your expected output? Also use `set.seed` when using `sample`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ActivityID) %>%
 summarise(Surface = any(Surface == "Gloves")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(Surface)

  Surface     n
  <lgl>   <int>
1 FALSE       1
2 TRUE        4
```

And as percentage:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ActivityID) %>%
 summarise(Surface = any(Surface == "Gloves")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 add_count() %>%
 group_by(Surface) %>%
 summarise(n = first(n()/n)) %>%
 ungroup()

  Surface     n
  <lgl>   <dbl>
1 FALSE     0.2
2 TRUE      0.8
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, thank you! Looks nice, but says "Object 'Surface' not found". I'm trying it with this particular df to just to make sure... I wonder what's happening. It looks like for you it worked?

Comment: I am using the df you provided. Cannot see a problem.

Comment: That's my fault, I'm sorry, I hadn't re-loaded dplyr after trying plyr. Thank you again for such a quick and smooth reply!